# Тире в предложении: "Крымские паразиты – лучшие"

Tags: пунктуация

*Крымские паразиты – лучшие*. Нужно ли тире?

Comment: Тире не надо, раков хороших в Крыму никогда не было, а теперь и плохих не осталось.

Comment: у меня в вопросе были паразиты, а не раки, кто-то изменил вопрос...

Comment: Тогда пардон. Кто и когда и что именно именно изменил можете посмотреть, нажав на ссылку вида "изменён 16 часов назад". Попадете сюда. rus.stackexchange.com/posts/428093/revisions – behemothus

Answer (score 3):

Если только как интонационное, чтобы подчеркнуть сказуемое

У Розенталя:

.1. Тире может ставиться для логического деления простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы уточнить или подчеркнуть смысловые отношения между членами предложения. Ср.: Ходить – долго не мог; Ходить долго – не мог. Такое тире называется интонационным, оно может отделять любую часть предложения, например: Я вас спрашиваю, рабочим – нужно платить? (Чехов).

2. Интонационный характер имеет также тире, которое может ставиться между членами предложения для выражения неожиданности, например: И щуку бросили – в реку (Крылов)
   http://www.tepka.ru/rozental_2/81.html

Answer (score 0):

Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: *Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый…* (П.); *Земля велика и прекрасна* (Ч.).

Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится при логическом или интонационном членении предложения:*Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные* (Ш.); *Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная* (Каз.) (Розенталь Д. Э.)

В Вашем случае возможно интонационное тире.

Answer (score 0):

**КрЫмские раки – лУчшие.**  В  предложении **такой структуры** ударение падет на первое слово, делается пауза, ставится тире.

Но: Хорошие у вас раки, но всё-таки  **крымские раки лучшие** (здесь авторское решение, тире можно ставить или не ставить).

Вообще говоря, постановка тире **зависит от структуры предложения**, поэтому возможны разные варианты, например:

(1) **НАши комедии ― лУчшие.** Ударение  на первом слове, пауза, тире.

(2) В мировом киноискусстве **наши комедии лУчшие,** их всегда смотрят миллионы телезрителей. Нет паузы и тире.

**И вывод**: тире ― это не только пауза, но и распределение логических ударений в предложении.

Answer (score 0):

После восстановления исторической справедливости в исторической битве раков и паразитов, брошу свои пять копеек.
Грамматика не изменилась, о ней - см. Людмила.

Но! В отличие от раков, паразиты явно свидетельствуют об ироничности, даже саркастичности фразы. А это располагает именно к интонационному тире.

Остальное тоже в силе, но куда менее актуально  для паразитов, чем для раков.

***С учетом стилистики тире вполне уместно, хотя и не обязательно.***